# Kotlin upload image to firebase is not working

Tags: firebase, kotlin

When I tried to run the program and upload the image to the firebase, it doesn't success... Anyone can help me.. It looks like the Task is not success but I have do some research and still can't solve it.

```
val fileRef :StorageReference =  storageProfilePicRef!!.child(firebaseUser!!.uid + ".jpg")
        var uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
        uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)

        uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>{ task ->
            if(!task.isSuccessful){
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                }
            }
            return@Continuation fileRef.downloadUrl

            //not able to download the image url successfully so cannot go in task.isSuccessful
        }).addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<Uri>{ task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this, "123.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val downloadUrl = task.result
                myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

                val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                userMap["fullname"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString().lowercase()
                userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString().lowercase()
                userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString().lowercase()
                userMap["image"] = myUrl

                ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

                Toast.makeText(this, "Account Information has been updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, task.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }
        })
```

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed? If yes, which one? Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, when I change to toast to 'task.toString()', it will display toast like 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw@66dd8de'. But I still don't know why it is not able to success run into the IF statement.....

Comment: `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw@66dd8de` it's the String representation of the object, which doesn't help. You need to wait for the task to be complete and then get the data out of the there.